# QGIS "open attribute table" as tab

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, panel

How open layer's attribute table as tab?

Before reinstall OS on QGIS 3.8 I opened layer's attribute table as tab, after on QGIS 3.10 I can't find this option.

Comment: what do you mean reinstall OS on QGIS 3.8.  Do you mean you reinstalled your OS    (which OS) and then you installed QGIS 10?  Please edit the question to add more details.

Comment: At the top of the window is a tab bar. After "open attribute table", first tab was main window, second (third, etc) was layer's attribute table. "Open new attribute tables as docked windows" isn't this option, it doesn't open as tab.

Answer (score 11):

Settings -> Options
Data Sources Tab

Check the box for "Open new attribute tables as docked windows"
[image]

Tabs will appear as such:
[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19295950/85338838-0a1b6500-b4b1-11ea-819c-e3ef0b90013f.png]

This functionality was merged into QGIS as of [PR 35933](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35933), and is in release 3.14

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is correct for changing the general behavior. If you want to change for a single session, you can use the button in the attribute table:

[image]

If you have many dock with the attribute table, you can make tabs by drag and drop one widget on top of the other one, it will give you tabs like this:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize you make tabs by dragging.  Thank you for highlighting.  I wish this could be made to be a default behavior.